# c++ min max question related to call by reference

Tags: c++, algorithm

ex) sample 1
input : 100 500, 
corrct result : 200 250,

ex) sample 2
input : 355 321,
correct result : 177 642

like this, smaller input has to be *2 and bigger one has to be /2.

and has to print out in order of input (I call it 't', 't2')

It looks very simple but i have to print then out in order they've passed. 
ex) 355 passed first, saved in 't' and modified, then printed first.

First, I tried to a'<'b? a:b or max() but got an issue with the 355 321 cases,
so I kept simplifying the function

my final code is this(ignore non-payload) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void sout(int& , int&,int &max, int& min);

int main()
{

    int ma, mn;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int t2;
    cin >> t2;
    sout(t,t2,ma,mn) ;
    cout << t << ' ' << t2;
}
void sout(int& t, int& t2 ,int &ma, int& mn)
{
    if (t > t2) {
        t /= 2;
        t2 *= 2;
    }

    if (t < t2) {
        t2 /= 2;
        t *= 2;
    }
}
```

However I've failed in test case 355, 321.
my code printed out 354, 321.
I mean what the xxxx man why 355 decreased by 1 and idk what happened and how come i passed other test cases? its just same numberS!!!

So I tried to use the address to compare(Since I have to use a fuction and use calling by references) so this part was fixed :

```
   if (&t > &t2) {
                t /= 2;
                t2 *= 2;
            }

    if (&t < &t2) {
                t2 /= 2;
                t *= 2;
            }
```

Then it worked. but failed in other cases like 35, 3 -> 70, 1

Can anyone explain to me this? I want structure to be same because I want the focus of the curiousty to be fixed here;

cheers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `if` for both conditions, for some cases both will be executed.

```
// t = 355, t2 = 321
if (t > t2) {
    t /= 2;
    t2 *= 2;
    // t = 177, t2 = 642
}
// t = 177, t2 = 642
if (t < t2) {
    t2 /= 2;
    t *= 2;
    // t = 354 , t2 = 321
}
// return t = 354 , t2 = 321
```

Use `else` for second condition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void sout(int& , int&,int &max, int& min);

int main()
{

    int ma, mn;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int t2;
    cin >> t2;
    sout(t,t2,ma,mn) ;
    cout << t << ' ' << t2;
}
void sout(int& t, int& t2 ,int &ma, int& mn)
{
    if (t > t2) {
        t /= 2;
        t2 *= 2;
    }
    else {
        t2 /= 2;
        t *= 2;
    }
}
```

Using ternary operator:

```
void sout(int& t, int& t2 ,int &ma, int& mn)
{   
    (t < t2) ? (t*=2, t2/=2) : (t/=2, t2*=2);
}
```

Comment: wow I was so stupid man thank you , However, can you also provide the solution with (a<b)?a:b Or max()min() ? it will be  mucho appriciated

Comment: @r3dr4bb1t add example for ternary operator.